# Norm of laplacian in dual space $H^{-2}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, laplacian, dual-spaces, extrapolation

how we can prove the estimate $\|\Delta u\|_{H^{-2}} \leq C \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $H^{-2}$ is the dual space of $H^{2}\cap H_0^1$. Can we get this estimate without using extrapolation spaces ? Thank for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Let suppose your laplacian is with Dirichlet boundaries conditions (i.e $H^2$ is in fact $H^2$ with $0$ as Dirichlet trace).

Let $v \in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ such that $v_{|\partial \Omega}=0$, by integration by parts:
$$|\langle \Delta u, v \rangle|=\left| \int_\Omega \Delta u v \right|=\left|\int_\Omega u \Delta v \right|\leq \|u|_{L^2} \|\Delta v\|_{L^2}$$
but $\|\Delta v\|_{L^2} \leq \|v\|_{H^2}$.

You obtain that for any sufficiently regular $v$:
$$|\langle \Delta u,v\rangle| \leq\|u\|_{L^2} \|v\|_{H_2}  $$
which gives the result by density.

Comment: Please, can you precise what you mean by $H^{-2}$ because i don't get the final result, is it the dual with the norm of $L^2$ or with the norm of $H^2 \cap H_0^1$ ?

Comment: The norm $H^{-2}$ is defined by:
$$\|w\|_{H^{-2}}=\inf_{\phi \in H^2 \cap H^1_0} \frac{|\langle w,\phi \rangle|}{\|\phi\|_{H^2}}$$

Comment: For the dual  norm it is the one from the $L^2$ inner product,  if $u$ and $v$ are in $L^2$:
$$\langle u,v\rangle =\int u v$$